# Find the number of dissimilar terms in expansion of $\left(1+x\right)^{2012}+\left(1+x^2\right)^{2011}+\left(1+x^3\right)^{2010}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of dissimilar terms in expansion of

$\left(1+x\right)^{2012}+\left(1+x^2\right)^{2011}+\left(1+x^3\right)^{2010}$

My attempt:
I tried using Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion:
$n(A)=2013,n(B)=2012,n(C)=2011$
But am getting confused finding terms common to two or three of the series.

Comment: What do you mean by "dissimilar terms?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think he means different terms (meaning different powers of $x$). But it is confusing though because it could mean not simplified.

Comment: It indeed means different powers of $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that counting the dissimilar terms is, given your expression, the same that counting the dissimilar terms of the expression 
$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^{2012})+(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{4022})+(1+x^3+x^6+...+x^{6030})$$

Now, using your notation, the answer will be $N(A)+N(B)+N(C)-N(A,B)-N(B,C)-N(A,C)+N(A,B,C)$

You calculated $N(A)+N(B)+N(C)$. Now:

$N(A,B)$] All the terms in $B$ less or equal to 2012 are in $A$. Then $N(A,B)=1007$ (cause exponents in $B$ are even)

$N(B,C)$] All the terms in $C$ of the form $6k$ less or equal to 4022 are in $B$. They are 0,6,12,18,...,4020. Then $N(B,C)=671$.

$N(A,C)$] All the terms in $C$ to 2012 are in $B$. They are 0,3,6,...2010. Then $N(B,C)=671$.

$N(A,B,C)$] It is easy to check that we are talking about the 6k on $A$ less or equal to 2012: 0,6,12,...,2010. That's 336

So, the answer is 2013+2012+2011-1007-671-671+336=4023